# Making a star with html

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a script and want to make the featured listings appear with a star right next to the listing, like here, cardealerscript.com/demo/

Although it works in some browsers, it does not work in mobile browsers.

I would like to keep it in html though, I dont want to use images.

Can anybody suggest another way to keep the star in html? I'm using this  ★ at the moment.

Thanks Anton

Comment: Well, there's this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ , but I can't promise it'd work in *all* mobile browsers.

Comment: It looks like they're using the same star you are with a larger font size. Am I missing something Anton Sarah?

Comment: Hey, Yeah, Sarah is my sister, she's sitting here while I'm asking questions. Sorry. She told me that this site is perfect for questions like these.

Comment: Hi Kobi, will those work on mobile browsers?

Answer (score 6):

★      `&#9733;`

black star from http://www.quackit.com/html/html_special_characters.cfm

Alternatively you can [base64 encode](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) whatever start you want and use that in css.

Comment: Isn't that the same character that he's currently using?

Comment: Might be, but I didn't check his source. Added to my answer though.

Answer (score 4):

I like font-awesome for this stuff:

http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it in pure CSS without a character entity needed at all. Check out [ShapesOfCSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) with the [6](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#star-six) and [5 pointed](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#star-five) star (and beyond). Browser compatibility will still need to be checked, however.

For a not-quite-a-star but very well supported, you could use a diamond, which is an html entity `&diams;` ♦ (or `&#9830;`). ([List](http://www.htmlentities.com/html/entities/))

I'm going to take a crack at answering the browser compatibility question. The 5-point start uses a few widely supported properties: [margin](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html#t12), [position](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/position.html), [display](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html), color, width, height, [border](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html), and top/left/right are all css 2.0 properties and haven't changed much (if at all?) for css 3. Css 2.1 reached 'recommended' status in *1998*, so these properties should all be uniformly supported in mobile browsers released for any phone that's still running. The original iPhone was released in 2007 with a mobile version of [Safari 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history). [Browser support on Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) is much sketchier, since manufacturers and end-users have many different options of which browser to use.

That just leaves the following properties:

```
-moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
```

`-moz-transform` refers to Mozilla, which means the [Gecko layout engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29). Support for [`-moz-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) starts in 13.5 with the `-moz` prefix and 16.0 for the standard CSS3 property `transform`.

Now, Safari uses the webkit rendering engine, which it shares with Chrome and [many other browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#Installed_base). Support for [`-webkit-transform`](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/webkit/css_-webkit-transform.cfm):

> **Availability**
> The -webkit-transform property is available in:
>
> For 2D transforms:
>
> - Safari 3.1 and later
> - iOS 2.0 and later
> - Google Chrome 1.0 and later

`-ms-transform` is supported in IE9.0 and later. It is deprecated in IE10, which favors the CSS3 standard `transform` property instead. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).) How that translates into windows mobile support, I don't know. But rest easy that Windows still captures single digits of marketshare in the mobile sphere.

`-o-transform` refers to Opera, which has actually transitioned to the webkit rendering engine. But that property was added in ['Presto 2.4'](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto24/css/transforms/), which was released with [Opera 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29) for both desktop and mobile, which appears to have been released on [December 10, 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mobile#History).

Oh, and if you do decide to use the css star, you should add the CSS3 `transform` property to any rule that requires it. I.e. add

```
transform:      rotate(35deg);
```

To the `star-five` rules,

```
transform:      rotate(-35deg);
```

To the `star-five:before` rules, and

```
transform:      rotate(-70deg);
```

To the `star-five:after` rules.

Answer (score 3):

[Font support to BLACK STAR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/fontsupport.htm) is limited, so the situation depends on installed fonts in a system more than on the browser. To overcome this limitation, you can use a suitable font (at least for the star) as a downloadable font via `@font-face`. There are several free fonts that contain BLACK STAR, such as DejaVu fonts, Linux Libertine, and Symbola. For general notes on using special characters, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

There are other approaches, too, of course. The simplest, and probably best, of the alternative solutions would be to use just an image, or a small set of images (containing varying number of stars), with adequate `alt` attributes.